# How to conduct a more effective search

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I have some doubts about a specific function. For example: [Sequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html) function.

But when I do a search it appears in the titles, in the body of text, ...

My intention is to search the term within the code only. In my example a person can comment on "sequence" and not necessarily use the function in context.

What should I do to make my research more effective?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the search operator **code:** to restrict a search to code fields, e.g.:

[`code:"Sequence"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=code%3A%22Sequence%22)

This search isn't perfect and it is not always clear (to me at least) what constitutes a complete token that can be searched for and what does not. Nevertheless it should be significantly more useful than simply searching for a bare string that is a common English word.

For more on search operators and other search options see:

- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/searching

(Strangely **code:** is not mentioned on this page that I can see; I don't know why.)

Comment: Is there a way to make search also be case-sensitive?

Comment: @Alexey searches are now deliberately case-insensitive, apparently; see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160820/158428